# WebApi: What is the difference between these 2 types of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This is the first time that i'm seeing this ways of doing things in a web-api.

So let me put you in context:

I have a web api where we have two routes:

## Method one:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("message-activity")]
public PagedResult<AuditedMessage> GetMessageActivity(int page)
{
}
```

## Method 2:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("message-activity/{messageID}")]
public AuditedMessage GetMessage(string messageID)
{
}
```

## My question is:

Talking about good practices in webApi's.
-Is the first method acceptable?
-Is it right?
-Is that anything wrong with the second method?

Thanks!

Comment: @mjwills Argh! For webserver a question you should always ask is: what is more secure. And ideally: what is more standard for a webserver / less surprising for consumers. And for both of those questions, the second one wins hands down.

Comment: `what is more secure.` Neither option is more or less secure than the other.

Comment: @jas Both options are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using first method, parameter will be specified using query string.
i.e : `message-activity?page=paramValue`

While Using second method, you can simply pass parameter in the API call URL
i.e : `message-activity/paramValue`

Both of the method will work equally

Answer (score 1):

In light of your edited question:
There might be something wrong, or it might not be.
To elaborate: The second version just returns a single result, the first one returns a paged list of results.
If I have an existing messageID and I am only interested in this message, the second one is the best.
If I need to to show a list of messages, the first one is vastly better.
On a normal CRUD Controller, I would expect both methods.

Comment: The first one has a [HttpGet] attribute on it. I just forget to add it. Sorry. When you say the route is not needed, you mean that without the {messageID} in the route, the second method will work?

Answer (score 0):

to be honest I don't like any of them.

why?

let's look at the first one:

```
GetMessageActivity(int page)
```

- What message?
- what does page mean?
- what's the page size?

if you want it to make sense and paginate the results then perhaps it could look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("message-activity")]
public PagedResult<MessageActivity> GetMessageActivity(string messageID, int pageSize, int pageNumber)
{
}
```

of course you'd update the route to match that.

That would make more sense to me. you return this MessageActivity data, whatever that is, not a message. If you want to return a message then return a message like in the second method.

Second one is strange as well:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("message-activity/{messageID}")]
public AuditedMessage GetMessage(string messageID)
{
}
```

Well, if you want to load a message than the route should be message, not message-activity.

Something like:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("message/{messageID}")]
    public AuditedMessage GetMessage(string messageID)
    {
    }
```

I would change both so they make sense. An API is written for clients and those clients need to understand very quickly what's going on.

You can't compare the two as they refer to different things. You want to work with a message then your route, params and outputs need to reflect that. If you want to work with this MessageActivity then let your endpoint reflect that

Comment: _"An API is written for clients and those clients need to understand very quickly what's going on"_ - an API is for machines. Sure, sensible and consistent naming are very useful, but documentation is also needed.

Comment: people write code, not machines. with good naming conventions documentation takes a secondary place. do I need to read documentation to see that an endpoint called message-activity actually loads message information? No, KISS all the way

Comment: Yeah but that's just your assumptions based on the very limited information given here. Perhaps in the domain of the OP's service, it makes sense to have an endpoint that provides information about "activities around messages", instead of simply messages.